# How to calculate powers and element-wise multiplication?

Tags: r, matlab, math, signal-processing

I need to convert the below line from Matlab into R

```
  z=(exp(j)).^(pw.*om)
```

In the matlab code, there is powers (.^) and multiplication(.*)

I have no idea how both are applied in r

The data:

```
  rt=10000
  f=200
  om = 2*pi*f/rt
  t = seq(0,1,length.out=rt)
  pw = c(1:length(t))
```

Here's some attempts but they did not provide the correct data

```
  zt=c(exp(sqrt(as.complex(-1))),(pw**om))

  zt=c(exp(sqrt(as.complex(-1))),`^`(pw,om))
```

this did not work

```
  zt=c(exp(sqrt(as.complex(-1))),`^`(pw*om))
```

Comment: Why do you put a comma? It's a multiplication.

Comment: @user22178063 `srate` is undefined.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the code did not work with multiplication

Comment: Try `z <- exp(1i)^(powers*omega)`. Equivalently, `exp(1i*powers*omega)`.

Comment: @jblood94, post as answer please ...

Comment: ChatGPT is decent at translating between coding languages. E.g. here it gives: "z <- (exp(1i))^(pw * om)" with the explanation "In R, the imaginary unit is represented by 1i, which is equivalent to j in MATLAB."

Answer (score 2):

Translating the MATLAB code to R:

### Imaginary numbers

To get the imaginary unit in MATLAB: `i`, `j`, or `complex(0, 1)`.

To get the imaginary unit in R: `1i` or `complex(1, 0, 1)`.

### Element-wise operation

For element-wise operations in MATLAB, prepend `.` to the operator (e.g., `.^` or `.*`).

Arithmetic operators in R are always element-wise.

### Final translation

Thus `z=(exp(j)).^(pw.*om)` in MATLAB becomes `z <- exp(1i)^(pw*om)` in R.

---

### Side note

Notice that `exp(x)^y == exp(x*y)`, so we can simplify the expression, improve performance, and get better precision with `z <- exp(1i*pw*om)`.

Comparing precision using MATLAB:

```
format long
disp(prod(exp(i).^(1:1e5)))
disp(prod(exp((1:1e5)*i)))
disp(double(prod(exp(vpa(i)).^vpa(1:1e5))))
disp(double(prod(exp(vpa(i).*vpa(1:1e5)))))
```

Returns

```
0.269134310362641 + 0.963102827984568i
0.269134003140172 + 0.963102740289812i
0.269134003140168 + 0.963102740289813i
0.269134003140168 + 0.963102740289813i
```

Comparing performance using `microbenchmark` in R:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  z1 = exp(1i)^(pw*om),
  z2 = exp(1i*pw*om)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#>    z1 796.4 813.75 831.254 823.00 838.35 1095.4   100
#>    z2 467.8 520.65 536.049 527.25 535.85  735.0   100
```

Answer (score 0):

the arraywise multiplication operator is simply `*` in r. and matrix multiplication operator is `%*%`. since division doesn't really exist for matrices you have `/` for devision and `%/%` for integer devision or getting qoutient. and power is simply ^ for anything.
for example:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- 1:5
c <- a * b
d <- a / b
e <- a ^ b
f <- a ^ 2
```